# Counting partition size in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm implementing unique entry counter in Cassandra. The counter may be represented just as a set of tuples:

```
counter_id = broadcast:12345, token = user:123
counter_id = broadcast:12345, token = user:321
```

where value for counter `broadcast:12345` may be counted as size of corresponding entries set. Such counter can be effectively stored as a table with `counter_id` being partition key. My first thought was that since single counter value is basically size of partition, i can do `count(1) WHERE counter_id = ?` query, which won't need to read data and would be super-duper fast. However, i see following trace output:

```
 cqlsh > select count(1) from token_counter_storage where id = '1';


 activity                                                                                        | timestamp                  | source     | source_elapsed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+------------+----------------
                                                                              Execute CQL3 query | 2016-06-10 11:22:42.809000 | 172.17.0.2 |              0
        Parsing select count(1) from token_counter_storage where id = '1'; [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-06-10 11:22:42.809000 | 172.17.0.2 |            260
                                                       Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-06-10 11:22:42.810000 | 172.17.0.2 |            565
                 Executing single-partition query on token_counter_storage [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-06-10 11:22:42.810000 | 172.17.0.2 |           1256
                                              Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-06-10 11:22:42.810000 | 172.17.0.2 |           1350
 Skipped 0/0 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-06-10 11:22:42.810000 | 172.17.0.2 |           1465
                                Merging data from memtables and 0 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-06-10 11:22:42.810000 | 172.17.0.2 |           1546
                                        Read 10 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-06-10 11:22:42.811000 | 172.17.0.2 |           1826
                                                                                Request complete | 2016-06-10 11:22:42.811410 | 172.17.0.2 |           2410
```

I guess that this trace confirms data being read from disk. Am i right in this conclusion, and if yes, is there any way to simply fetch partition size using index without any excessive disk hits?

Comment: Cassandra is bad at counting. That said if you really want to count (as you mentioned approximately) in some specific use case, Cassandra counters would be a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660382/cassandra-operationtimedout/37663041#37663041

Comment: @yurgis i am afraid i can't do that because of uniqueness count restriction. The application i'm delivering doesn't have specific purpose (it's more like "general counter service", by the way it has simple sequential counters as well), so i can't predict how much loss client may tolerate. I'm currently using one-second cache for counter that will be tunable later, so i shouldn't send such requests too often.

Comment: Ok, got it. BTW uniqueness in principle could be resolved by light wait transactions, but that would probably defeat your service purpose, as it is way more expensive.

Comment: I am hitting the same issue. What did you end up doing? My guess is that the problem is that clustering indexes with variable row size are hard to count.

Comment: @user3711864 i've ended up with storing counted value as separate value with background count-then-update process, as far as i remember (data correctness would be great, but i could afford some fluctuations). As for index analysis, i guess, it may be a little bit harder than i thought - there is no 1-to-1 correlation (one record may span across several SSTs),   too many things cloaked in internals, so there is possibility index itself doesn't know how many records are inside.